# Conditional renaming of data frame columns

Tags: r, string, dplyr, rename

I have (1) a data frame with many columns (`df`), (2) a character vector whose elements may or may not be the names of the data frame columns (`search_for_these`), and (3) a character containing strings that should replace each element of the aforementioned vector if the data frame contains the specified column (`replace_with_these`).

```
df <- data.frame(
  dat = rep(1:2),
  bat = seq(1:2),
  cat = c("foo","bar"))

search_for_these <- c("dat", "bat", "shoe", "box")
replace_with_these <- c("cow", "bat2", "shoes", "boxes")
```

My goal is to replace any element of `search_for_these` found in `colnames(df)` with the value found in the same index of `replace_with_these`. The desired result is therefore:

```
df <- data.frame(
  cow = rep(1:2),
  bat2 = seq(1:2),
  cat = c("foo","bar"))
```

I thought of using `dplyr::contains()` for this but it's not clear how to actually implement this.

Answer (score 4):

While we can use `match`, we need to make sure we replace the elements that are matched in our initial data frame and not the indices of the matching vector which may refer to different variables in the primary data frame!

As akrun noted, we first `match` but then we replace the elements of the primary vector containing the matches using subsetting `[]` and `%in%`:

```
found <- match(colnames(df), search_for_these, nomatch = 0)
colnames(df)[colnames(df) %in% search_for_these] <- replace_with_these[found]
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do this with `match`

```
i1 <- match(colnames(df), search_for_these, nomatch = 0)
colnames(df)[i1] <- replace_with_these[i1]
```

Comment: Simple, transparent!

Comment: When I implement this with my actual data, I am finding that colnames(df)[i1] contains the variables found at the indices in [i1]. These are not necessarily the same as the indices of the column names that need to be replaced. In other words, colnames(df)[i1] shows the wrong variables because [i1] is the index from **the vector**. So, colnames(df)[i1] <- replace_with_these[i1] is replacing the wrong values in colnames(df).

Comment: Took me a second to see, too, but the error in this answer is clear if one of the column names in the sample data frame, df, has an index in search_for_these / replace_with_these that is greater than the number of columns in df. For example, before running this answer, replace the first column name with colnames(df)[1] <- "box".

Comment: @akrun I implemented this in a project, but it threw an error. Then I noticed QuestionAnswer's comment above and QuestionAnswer's new answer. Perhaps QuestionAnswer should have requested an edit instead of creating an answer. The issue: i1 is not the correct index for colnames(df). Change the look-up table order - search_for_these <- c("bat", "shoe", "box", "dat"), replace_with_these <- c("bat2", "shoes", "boxes", "cow") - and it breaks. I upvoted QuestionAnswer's corrected answer and downvoted this so the correct might appear first. Let me know if I missed something.